# Fragments system in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, fragment

I was wondering if CakePHP has something similar to the fragments in Ruby on Rails ?

I've found something [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#displaying-blocks), but, when I try this with a `test.ctp` in the `Elements` folder

```
<?php echo $this->fetch("/Elements/test"); ?>
```

Nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way ?

Comment: [View blocks are new in version 2.1](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html) Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $this->element('test');`, instead of fetch?

Comment: Yep... It was that simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Elements don't work like that

[Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) are I assume the equivalent of fragments. The [element](http://api.cakephp.org/class/view#method-Viewelement) method is used to return the contents of an element (a file containing a chunk of view code):

```
echo $this->element('some'); // output View/Elements/some.ctp
```

### Fetch is for returning a view block

[Fetch](http://api.cakephp.org/class/view#method-Viewfetch) is a method used to return the contents of a view block - some pre-rendered, in memory string:

```
// app/View/Common/view.ctp
<h1><?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

<div class="actions">
    <h3>Related actions</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('sidebar'); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```